# Problema ao passar hora do Angular para C# Core

Tags: c#, angular, data

O problema consiste em passar um valor hora através de um método observable (Angular 8) para uma controller (C# Core 2.2), no momento do envio dos dados está correto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No entanto, quando recebo os valores, está somado automaticamente +3 horas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No momento estou rodando localmente (localhost), **qual melhor abordagem para resolver o problema de timezone de forma global**? Desde já agradeço!

Comment: Provalvelmente o problema é que o browser e seu servidor estão em timezones diferentes

Comment: Sim, como devo proceder para configurar o .net core p/ não somar +3 horas de forma global? Para sempre pegar a hora fornecida.

Comment: Sinceramente não entendo porque alguns usuários votam negativo para a pergunta, qual o problema com a pergunta? Ao invés de simplesmente julgar deveria ajudar...

Comment: Consegui adicionando mais uma parâmetro na conversão: ligacao.data_ligacao = new Date(this.datePipe.transform(data_ligacao, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", "GMT-6")), isso está correto? Devo proceder dessa maneira para todas as datas que encaminharei? Isso não me parece consistente...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trabalhar com datas sempre é um desafio, portanto é essencial que alguém dite a regra sobre qual timezone usar. O normal é se o UTC (que seria a hora/fuso-horario "zero") como padrao, pq a partir dai voce so precisa aplicar o fuso-horario do usuario.

Se precisar forcar esse comportamento no javascript voce pode usar o [getUTCDate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCDate). Mas caso precise tratar isso server-side voce pode usar o [ToUniversalTime()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.touniversaltime?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_DateTime_ToUniversalTime)

Dessa forma todos conversam no mesmo fuso-horario, e voce so precisa tratar a apresentacao para que seja apresentada da maneira correta.

Answer (score 0):

Pela imagem apresentada, não há qualquer erro. Parte do `DateTime` é o fuso horário, que no Brasil é sempre GMT-3 (uma vez que não há mais o horário de verão). O horário apresentado no Angular indica que está em GMT. Há diversas maneiras de tratar o fuso horário no front end, a mais fácil deverá ser com o uso de bibliotecas como o [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/).

Olhando para a imagem do backend, o horário terá a componente "normal" de hora e também o fuso horário. O ideal é sempre trabalhar com UTC, evitando esse tipo de problema e converter o horário somente na camada de apresentação, tendo em conta o fuso horário do usuário.

---

Side note: UTC e GMT não é a mesma coisa "filosoficamente" falando, mas no fundo terá o mesmo resultado. Portanto o "GMT" que vc está vendo no Angular seria equivalente ao UTC no `DateTime.UtcNow` no .Net.

Comment: Brasil é GMT -3

Comment: Eu necessito que o back-end receba exatamente a hora que estou passando, independente do fuso horário, pois o usuário está definindo esse horário para exercer determinada atividade. O que devo configurar no back-end para que não aconteça essa conversão?

Comment: @MarceloVismari, obrigado. Corrigido.

Comment: @Alessandro o erro não está no backend, mas no front end. É um risco assumir que todos os clientes enviarão a data com o mesmo fuso horário. Vc deveria ver os componentes que são usados no front para se certificar que adiciona o fuso horário do cliente na data que é passada para a sua api. Caso contrário, não conseguirá fazer a converão sem gambiarras, uma vez que vc assume que o horário passado está em outro fuso horário, vc teria que ver o datetime offset do servidor e multiplicar por 2, para então adicionar ou subtrair da data recebida.